# React ChartJS Scatter Plot - cannot plot the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am trying to generate a scatterplot using chartJS. The plot wont graph.
When i feed in data manually by declaring the data, it works fine,

```
var scatter = [
        { x: 65, y: 75 },
        { x: 59, y: 49 },
        { x: 80, y: 90 },
        { x: 81, y: 29 },
        { x: 56, y: 36 },
        { x: 55, y: 25 },
        { x: 40, y: 18 },
      ]
```

but when I get the data via an API call and push the data to the array, it won't work. Any suggestions? I suspect its to do with how data is pushed onto the array but not sure what's wrong.

Thank you

Minimum solution below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
    const [scatterData, setScatterData] = useState({});

    const chart = () => {
        var scatter = [];
        
        axios.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
        .then(res => {
            let temp = res.data.data
            temp.forEach( i=> {
                let age = parseInt(i.employee_age)
                let salary = parseInt(i.employee_salary)
                scatter.push({"x": age,
                             "y": salary})
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        console.log(scatter)

 

        setScatterData({
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'test',
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 10,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: scatter,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 4
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    useEffect(() ={
        chart()
    },[])

    return (
        <div className ="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div className ="col-md-12">
                    <Scatter data={scatterData}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the update method on your chart object/instance after you pushed all the data from the api to your scatter array